# Cannot find symbol error Java

Tags: java

So I was creating this random string generator:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String strings = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%&()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
  int stringLength = strings.length()-1;
  Character character;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
      Double test = new Double(Math.random());
      character = strings.charAt(test.intValue());
      String outputString = outputString.concat(character.toString());
    }
    System.out.println(outputString);
  }
}
```

I went an compiled it using javac Test.java, and it gave me the error outputString might not have been initialised for lines 14 and 16. So I added the String keyword to line 14, and now it's telling me
`cannot find symbol: variable outputString`

Why is this so?

**EDIT:**

Okay so I took up the suggestions, and this is the code currently:

```
public class Test {
  public static int randomInt(int min, int max, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) - min;
    return randomNum;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String strings = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%&()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  int stringLength = strings.length()-1;
  Character character;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
      Double test = new Double(randomInt(0, stringLength, System.currentTimeMillis()));
      character = strings.charAt(test.intValue());
      System.out.print(character);
    }
  }
}
```

The code runs without errors, but it doesn't print anything.
I'm currently using Command Prompt to compile it.

Comment: Your code is only 14 lines long. How can there be an error on line 16?

Comment: I had an import line before `public class test`

Comment: It would be better if you didn't refer to line numbers in your question. Even if they're correct, do you really expect us to count lines?

Comment: "Doesn't print anything": Maybe you need to have a `System.out.println();` at the end to flush the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work using the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test{

    public static void print(String str) {
      System.out.print(str);
    }

    public static int randomInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) - min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String strings = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%&()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int len = strings.length() - 1;
        StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Double test = new Double(randomInt(0, len));
            Integer value = test.intValue();
            if (value <= len) {
                //print(value.toString()); For testing purposes
                outputString.append(strings.charAt(value));
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            else {i--;}
        }
        print(outputString + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the `outputString` only inside of the `for` loop. It will not be available outside.

You could output the characters directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
  Double test = new Double(Math.random());
  character = strings.charAt(test.intValue());
  System.out.print(character);
}
System.out.println();
```

If you insist on concatenating a String in a loop, please use `StringBuilder` instead.

---

The next problem you will run into:

```
Double test = new Double(Math.random());
strings.charAt(test.intValue());
```

That will always get the the first character. The double will be between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

You need to [create a random integer between 0 and the length of your alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java).

Comment: When I defined outputString outside the loop, it gave me two errors that said outputString may not have been initialized

Comment: You want to initialize it to the empty String (`""`);

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correctly telling that `outputString` is not declared correctly. The `outputString` is declared within the `for` loop, but you are trying to print the value outside.

A quick way to fix this would be to declare `outputString` outside the `for` loop by having `outputString = ""`;

Comment: Thanks changed it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

`outputString` is only defined within the block of the `for` loop, so once you exit it, it no longer exists. To make sure that your code works, define it outside the loop:

```
String outputString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    Double test = new Double(Math.random());
    character = strings.charAt(test.intValue());
    outputString += character.toString();
}
System.out.println(outputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling outputString.concat before you have intialized it
try

```
String outputString = "";
outputString = outputString.concat(character.toString());`
```